# Simple bisection geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, circles, bisection

Let $\triangle ABC$ have incenter $D$ and let the incircle intersect sides $BC,AB,AC$ at $E,F,G$ respectively. Extend $AB$ and $AC$ to meet the circumcircle of $\triangle ADE$ at $K$ and $I$ respectively. Prove that $FG$ bisects $KI$. [image]

I have solved this with barycentric coordinates, but I would like to see a synthetic solution as it may be more elegant.

We employ a barycentric coordinate syst¹em. We list the coordinates of the points that we know. Here $s$ denotes the semiperimeter of $\triangle{ABC}$, so $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
E = (0 : s-c : s-b) \\
F = (s-c : 0 : s-a) \\
G = (s-b : s-a : 0) \\
D = (a : b : c) \\
A = (1 : 0 : 0) \\
B = (0 : 1 : 0) \\
C = (0 : 0 : 1).
\end{align*}
We also know that the equation of $AB$ is $z=0$ and the equation of $AC$ is $y=0$. Thus we simply have to find the equation of the circumcircle of $\triangle{ADE}$ and the equation of line $KI$ and $FG$ and show that it intersects at the desired points.

Comment: 1/ You might want to set up the question properly first. 2/ You might want to state your barycentric coordinates solution.

Comment: smells like Menelaus to me - although one could argue it follows from coordinate bashing.

Comment: How would this work?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\angle DIK = \angle DAF = \frac 12 \angle CAB = \angle CAD = \angle IKD,$$
hence $DK=DI$. Therefore the projection of $D$ onto $IK$ is the midpoint of $IK$. Note that $F$ is the projection of $D$ onto $AK$ and $G$ is the projection of $D$ onto $AI$. By Simson theorem, these three projections are collinear (they lie on the Simson line of $D$ with respect to $\triangle AKI$). This shows that $GF$ passes through the midpoint of $IK$.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a very easy solution. Notice that $\angle DKI=\angle DAI= \frac{\angle A}{2}$ and $\angle DIK =\angle DAF= \frac{\angle A}{2}.$ So, $DK=DI.$ Moreover, $KF^2=DK^2-DF^2$ and $IG^2=DI^2-DG^2$. Hence, we have $KF=IG.$ Now, by the law of sines in $\triangle KFL$ and $\triangle LGI$,

$$\frac{KL}{\sin \angle KFL}=\frac{KF}{\sin \angle KLF}, \\ \frac{LI}{\sin \angle LGI}=\frac{LI}{\sin \angle AGF}=\frac{IG}{\sin \angle GLI}.$$

Having $KF=IG$ and $\angle AGF=\angle KFL$, we are done.
[image]